# Kibana server is not ready yet - [security_exception] unable to authenticate user [elastic]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

What happen is I tried to add user for ElasticSearch and Kibana. For ElasticSearch, I added `xpack.security.enabled: true` at elasticsearch.yml and `elasticsearch.username: "elastic"` and `elasticsearch.password: "ipF2vorNqvRgXTjuptqS"` in kibana.yml.

When I start ElasticSearch, I was prompted to key in username and password. I did so and successfully login.

But when I start Kibana, in the log I get this error:  `[warning][licensing][plugins] License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch due to [security_exception] unable to authenticate user [elastic] for REST request [/_xpack]`

At http://localhost:5601, I got this error `Kibana server is not ready yet`

To troubleshoot, I run http://localhost:9200/_security/user/ and I get

```
{
   "elastic":{
      "username":"elastic",
      "roles":[
         "superuser"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   },
   "kibana":{
      "username":"kibana",
      "roles":[
         "kibana_system"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_deprecated":true,
         "_deprecated_reason":"Please use the [kibana_system] user instead.",
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   },
   "kibana_system":{
      "username":"kibana_system",
      "roles":[
         "kibana_system"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   },
   "logstash_system":{
      "username":"logstash_system",
      "roles":[
         "logstash_system"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   },
   "beats_system":{
      "username":"beats_system",
      "roles":[
         "beats_system"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   },
   "apm_system":{
      "username":"apm_system",
      "roles":[
         "apm_system"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   },
   "remote_monitoring_user":{
      "username":"remote_monitoring_user",
      "roles":[
         "remote_monitoring_collector",
         "remote_monitoring_agent"
      ],
      "full_name":null,
      "email":null,
      "metadata":{
         "_reserved":true
      },
      "enabled":true
   }
}
```

I follow the steps to setup my password at elasticsearch.

```
D:\elasticsearch\bin>elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto
future versions of Elasticsearch will require Java 11; your Java version from [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre] does not meet this requirement
Initiating the setup of passwords for reserved users elastic,apm_system,kibana,kibana_system,logstash_system,beats_system,remote_monitoring_user.
The passwords will be randomly generated and printed to the console.
Please confirm that you would like to continue [y/N]y


Changed password for user apm_system
PASSWORD apm_system = TCxggBZ1O8u7pCYMQZx3

Changed password for user kibana_system
PASSWORD kibana_system = G48r4h6M6WjLnjzPqjAG

Changed password for user kibana
PASSWORD kibana = G48r4h6M6WjLnjzPqjAG

Changed password for user logstash_system
PASSWORD logstash_system = UQZTsQrN84jQuzCKnOSc

Changed password for user beats_system
PASSWORD beats_system = wC5h5tShmOuouJ072owM

Changed password for user remote_monitoring_user
PASSWORD remote_monitoring_user = VHqOCfKuxbCCjbEMTWQZ

Changed password for user elastic
PASSWORD elastic = ipF2vorNqvRgXTjuptqS
```

How do I troubleshoot this further or solve this? Should I use "elastic" or "kibana_system" as username in kibana.yml?

This is kibana.yml

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
#server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
#server.host: "localhost"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
#server.name: "your-hostname"

# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: "ipF2vorNqvRgXTjuptqS"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"

#elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
#elasticsearch.password: "ipF2vorNqvRgXTjuptqS"

#elasticsearch.username: "kibana_system"
#elasticsearch.password: "kibanapassword"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the password too in kibana.yml file: `elasticsearch.password:$password`

Check the docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/using-kibana-with-security.html

Comment: I try to add password but still same error. I also tried to use "kibana_system" user but aso get the same error.

Comment: After adding the password, you have to restart your kibana process

Comment: I restarted kibana but still the same error

Comment: I updated my post for more info.  Should I use "elastic" or "kibana_system" as username in kibana.yml?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your kibana.yml file

Comment: Can you try using 'kibana' user instead of 'elastic'?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **config** > **kibana.yml** in kibana folder.

Change this

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["https://172.35.92.97:9200"]
```

to

```
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://172.35.92.97:9200"].
```

Make comment followings :

```
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [/Users/ozgurhanpolat/Downloads/kibana-8.11.1/data/ca_1704372255930.crt]
```

and

```
xpack.fleet.outputs: [{id: fleet-default-output, name: default, is_default: true, is_default_monitoring: true, type: elasticsearch, hosts: ['https://172.35.92.97:9200'], ca_trusted_fingerprint: b2aed3603d21e57e369af8e9960f94b20a7d93f6b91aac219c908fdd189d737f}] .
```

Save it and close kibana and run it again.

**Don't forget** you have to configure kibana and run at least one time before above.

Note that This works in **kibana 8.11.1** and **elasticsearch 8.11.1** versions.